# How do I convert an approximation to a machine number for use as coordinate argument in Epilog[,,Line[]]?

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to create a simple graph for an economics lecture. I want to add a vertical line to emphasize the fact the x solutions for f[x]==g[x] and f2[x]==g2[x] are the same.

This works fine if I hard code the Epilog[,,Line[]] coordinates as, say, {{0,0},{0,2}}. But when I attempt to pass variables from NSolveValues[] I get the error "Coordinate {{1.}, 0} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form."

I don't believe the "scaled" or "offset" suggestions apply here. I think M. is complaining that I'm using an approximation instead of a machine number.

Can I convert the NSolveValues[] result to a machine number or to something that Epilog[,,Line]] will accept? I've tried various manipulations with N[] and precision attributes, but I'm not getting anywhere.

```
ClearAll
p1 = 1.25;
p2 = 1.5;
f[x_] := p1*x;
f2[x_] := p2*x;
g[x_] := p1*(2 - x);
g2[x_] := p2*(2 - x);
equil = NSolveValues[f[x] == g[x], x]
equil2 = NSolveValues[f2[x] == g2[x], x]
Show[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}, PlotRange -> {0, 2},
  Epilog -> {Gray, Dashed, Line[{{equil, 0}, {equil2, 2}}]}
  ],
 Plot[f2[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Dashed}],
 Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Orange}],
 Plot[g2[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Orange, Dashed}]]
```

Thanks, TB

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at equil you can see that it is {1.} and you want it to be just 1. Hence you can change

```
{{equil, 0}, {equil2, 2}}
```

to

```
{{equil[[1]], 0}, {equil2[[1]], 2}}
```

and you get your gray line.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it's not working.

Comment: This is the full comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it's not working.  `equil[[0]]` returns 'List' (and M. replaces the brackets with a double bracket symbol). equil[Part[0] returns {1.}[0].  The errors are: "Coordinate {List, 0} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.", "Coordinate {{1.}[0], 0} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.". (BTW, this is M 13.2.1 on a MacPro M2.)

Comment: Try starting from a fresh kernel. When I ran your code the picture appeared just as above. Look at equil[[1]], not equil[[0]].

Comment: Again, thanks. I had to completely shut down and restart M, but now it works. Next up, we'll see how it works with non-integers.  :-)